Нужна ли запятая при сравнительном обороте?
Каждый из домочадцев живёт, словно в капсуле, ключ к замку которой не имеют даже родные.

Словно можно выкинуть, и посмотреть, что получится: каждый живёт в капсуле - не нужна запятая, значит, и в обороте не нужна. Также "каждый из домочадцев живёт" - довольно бессодержательная фраза, а с "...живёт в капсуле" - уже полноценная.

Правильно:
Каждый из домочадцев живёт словно в кАпсуле, ключ к замку которой не имеют даже роднЫе.
Пояснение
Оборот нельзя обособить, так как он входит в основной состав предложения: к нему относится определительное придаточное. Оборот находится в ударной позиции,  а на сказуемое ударение не падает (одно ударение, нет паузы).
Примечание

Оборот не входит в трехчастную сравнительную конструкцию, сравнить:
Каждый живёт в своем доме, словно в капсуле, при этом ключ к замку  не имеют даже родные. Здесь сравниваются формы "в своем доме, как в капсуле" через отношение к действию "живет".

Такие обороты желательно различать: их можно условно назвать уподоблением без повтора (живет как в капсуле) и сравнением с повтором (живет в доме, как в капсуле).

При уподоблении союз можно убрать из предложения, при этом грамматическая структур сохраняется: Каждый из домочадцев живёт в капсуле, ключ к замку которой не имеют даже родные.

Обороты без повтора обособляются значительное реже, в то время как при повторе обособление считается основной нормой. Причем в первую очередь это касается союзов словно, как будто, будто, точно, которые характерны для художественного сравнения.


Розенталь.
